# How do I keep the dropdown icon remains display without hover the mouse and the click action

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Hello I am debugging an old old codes.  Customer want the dropdown icos to remain appear, as our user think that the icon is missing.  After debugging with chrome tool, looks like the icon is there, it just need mouse hover and clicking action to display.
I am using the Infragistics MVC Assembly with the Html extension helper.  The ui controller calls Combo()

Here is the codes and chrome debugging image.  Your help/suggestion will be greatly appreciated

```html
<div class="" style="float:left;position:relative;left:0;top:0;padding:20px;width:25%;border-left:1px ridge;height:374px">
        <label style="float:None;">Delta Amt: </label>
        <input style="float:None; width: 150px;" id="DeltaAmt" onchange="ActivateSaveButton()" name="DeltaAmt" value="@bill.DeltaAmt" readonly />
        <br />
        <label style="float:None;">Delta Category: </label>
    
        <div>

            @(Html.Infragistics().Combo()
                                 .ID("cboDelta")
                                 .Width("270px")
                                 .DataSource(Url.Action("deltacategories-combo-data"))
                                 .AutoComplete(true)
                                 .ValueKey("DeltaCategoryID")
                                 .TextKey("DeltaCategoryName")
                                 .SelectedValues(bill.DeltaCategoryID.ToString())
                                 .AddClientEvent("selectionChanged", "ActivateSaveButton()")
                                 .DataBind()
                                 .Render()
               )

        </div>
        <label id="billingID" hidden>@bill.BillID.ToString()</label><br />
        <label style="float:None;">Delta Explanation: </label><br />
        <textarea rows="4" maxlength="500" style="width:400px" name="DeltaExplanation" onchange="ActivateSaveButton()" id="DeltaExplanation">@bill.DeltaExplanation</textarea><br />
        <label style="float:None;">NBR Explanation: </label><br />
        <textarea rows="4" maxlength="500" style="width:400px" name="NBRExplanation" onchange="ActivateSaveButton()" id="NBRExplanation">@bill.NBRExplanation</textarea><br />
        <label style="float:None;">Notes: </label><br />
        <textarea rows="4" maxlength="500" style="width:400px" name="Notes" onchange="ActivateSaveButton()" id="NotesTextArea">@bill.Notes</textarea>
    </div>
```

Here is the chrome debugging, when the mouse is hover over, the ui-state-hover is adding to the css
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IuiXF.png)

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution within the Infragistics Combo controller - when the mouse is hover over it use a specific background image, I change the none hover, the issue is fixed.

Code
/*.ui-icon,.ui-widget-content .ui-icon,.ui-state-default .ui-icon,.ui-widget-header .ui-state-default .ui-icon,.ui-iggrid-paging-item.ui-state-default .ui-icon{background-image:url(images/ui-icons_888888_256x240.png)}
*/

.ui-icon, .ui-widget-content .ui-icon, .ui-state-default .ui-icon, .ui-widget-header .ui-state-default .ui-icon, .ui-iggrid-paging-item.ui-state-default .ui-icon {
background-image: url(images/ui-icons_ffffff_256x240.png)
}